# Error when importing mysql database (about 80mb's) using BigDump

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql

So I have this mysql database that is way to huge to import via phpmyadmin. When I set it up with bigdump I get this error right off the bat

> Stopped at the line 339.

At this place the current query includes more than 300 dump lines. That can happen if your dump file was created by some tool which doesn't place a semicolon followed by a linebreak at the end of each query, or if your dump contains extended inserts."

So after 300 lines with no break it crashes. I went in and pasted this string in line 200 just to make sure that much was correct:

```
INSERT DELAYED INTO `invites_statistic` 
(`user_id`,`purchaseid`,`prodid`,`reg_length`,`invites_count`,`used`,`code`)
VALUES
```

I tried changing the length of the "Maximum length of created query" in phpmyadmin but then I was getting even more errors telling me I couldn't have that string in certain places.
I jumped around the SQL file adding the previous string a few lines before everytime it broke and that was working but this is a HUGE file 400k lines. Anyone know a good solution? Am I doomed?

Comment: Try redoing the dump with `--skip-extended-insert`, so each row gets its own insert statement, rather than multiple rows for each insert. It'll make the dump file much larger, but will vastly decrease the per-insert size.

Comment: Should I still use delayed inserts?

Comment: Only if something else is using the database at the time you're loading the dump. Otherwise it's useless.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will post the solution now.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by changing the `$max_query_lines` value from 300 to a higher number.

```
// How many lines may be considered to be one query (except text lines)
$max_query_lines = 10000;
```